# BrowserSync loads different root directory on two computers with the same code

Tags: browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

There is one project in Git repository and there are 2 computers that both pulled the latest version of the source code. So they run exactly the same code.

I use gulp together with the BrowserSync npm module and I pass only one option:

```
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        directory: true
    }
});
```

On one computer I can see it correctly loads the root folder of the project but on the other computer it loads node_modules/.bin directory as root. I can't figure out what can be different on these computers.

I made sure there is browser-sync installed globally and there is registered $PATH to global node_modules.

But I can't think of anything else. What is causing this different behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have time to troubleshoot this for a while. So I continued using the computer where it was working correctly. After 10 days I tried that again and it's just working. I assume it was some kind of **cache**. Because no matter how I updated the config, the BrowserSync didn't change its behavior. So I would recommend restarting everything possible. BrowserSync, Web server, computer.

If somebody has a more specific answer to what kind of cache it could be, I'll accept their answer as the correct one. I just want to leave it here to at least point somebody else to a direction that would help me.